# Default gateway route being automatically added to main table

Tags: networking, 20.04, netplan, routing

I have 2 network interfaces connected to my machine. (Fwiw it's an aws instance with the primary (default) ENI and an additional, secondary ENI attached, each with a public and private IP address associated.)

I've added a second routing table, introduced table rules and added and deleted a couple of routes in the main table as well as the additional table to my preference.

Everything works fine, except periodically, an additional unwanted (breaks things) default gateway route is added to the main table. **What is the daemon responsible for this?**

---

For good measure in case it's relevant here is my configuration:

The contents of `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`:

```
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens5:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: 06:c5:b4:81:5d:a2
            set-name: ens5
        ens6:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: 06:23:d7:eb:f9:f1  # ENI assigned
            set-name: ens6
```

`main` table:

```
default via 10.1.2.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp src 10.1.2.251 metric 100 
10.1.2.0/24 dev ens5 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.2.251 
10.1.2.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp scope link src 10.1.2.251 metric 100
```

`rt2` table:

```
default via 10.1.2.1 dev ens6 src 10.1.2.34 
10.1.2.0/24 dev ens6 scope link src 10.1.2.34
```

Routing table `rt2` is stable, but the `main` table *will not* contain a single default gateway for long. Sometimes I can terminate ssh session and return and everything is unchanged; other times if I wait a little longer, when I ssh back in the new default gateway is added. Something in Ubuntu 20.04, maybe in netplan or the dhcp daemon or possibly aws(?) or maybe something else, is periodically adding the following 2 lines back into the `main` table:

```
default via 10.1.2.1 dev ens6 proto dhcp src 10.1.2.34 metric 100
10.1.2.1 dev ens6 proto dhcp scope link src 10.1.2.34 metric 100
```

I can delete them again with a command like `sudo ip  route del default via 10.2.1.1 dev ens6` but they never cease to be re-added. This results in an asymmetric routing situation as is very inconvenient as it breaks my ssh connection to iface `ens6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite likely that this is coming from the DHCP server.  You have enabled DHCP and have not specified that you don't want to take routes from the DHCP server.

To avoid this, you can specify:

```
dhcp4-overrides:
  use-routes: false
```